# Convert supertrend from pinescript to javascript

Tags: javascript, pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

Firstly thanks for any help its a bit of a complex question!

I have a hobby of converting pinescript scripts to javascript which i then use to run through a backtester infra i built in js.  Just to start i am doing this with many scripts successfully, the problem wont be that im sending candles wrong or something.

I am 95% sure that my problem lies within not doing the ATR correct.  I have messed with this function a bit and get a little close but not exact.  Im pretty sure i converted the supertrend part correct though.

Lets start with the pinescript script of [supertrend](https://www.tradingview.com/script/r6dAP7yi/) by KivancOzbilgic:

```js
//@version=4
study("Supertrend", overlay = true, format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")

Periods = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=10)
src = input(hl2, title="Source")
Multiplier = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0)
changeATR= input(title="Change ATR Calculation Method ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
showsignals = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Signals ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
highlighting = input(title="Highlighter On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
atr2 = sma(tr, Periods)
atr= changeATR ? atr(Periods) : atr2
up=src-(Multiplier*atr)
up1 = nz(up[1],up)
up := close[1] > up1 ? max(up,up1) : up
dn=src+(Multiplier*atr)
dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)
dn := close[1] < dn1 ? min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend
upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title="Up Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.green)
buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title="UpTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title="Down Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.red)
sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title="DownTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, transp=0)
plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title="Sell", text="Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
mPlot = plot(ohlc4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)
longFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == 1 ? color.green : color.white) : color.white
shortFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == -1 ? color.red : color.white) : color.white
fill(mPlot, upPlot, title="UpTrend Highligter", color=longFillColor)
fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title="DownTrend Highligter", color=shortFillColor)
alertcondition(buySignal, title="SuperTrend Buy", message="SuperTrend Buy!")
alertcondition(sellSignal, title="SuperTrend Sell", message="SuperTrend Sell!")
changeCond = trend != trend[1]
alertcondition(changeCond, title="SuperTrend Direction Change", message="SuperTrend has changed direction!")
```

Here is my implementation in javascript

```js
// candles example (I provide 100 candles)
const candles = [{high: 10, low: 8, close: 9, open: 8.5}, ...]

static ATR = async (candles, multiplier, limit) => {
    const lows = candles.map((candle) => +candle.low)
    const highs = candles.map((candle) => +candle.high)
    const closes = candles.map((candle) => +candle.close)
    let TRResults = []
    for (let x = 1; x < candles.length; x++) TRResults.push(Math.max(highs[x] - lows[x], Math.abs(highs[x] - closes[x - 1]), Math.abs(lows[x] - closes[x - 1])))
    let RMA_TR_Results = [TRResults[0]]
    const alpha = 1 / limit
    for (let x = 1; x < TRResults.length; x++) RMA_TR_Results.push((alpha * TRResults[x]) + ((1 - alpha) * RMA_TR_Results[RMA_TR_Results.length - 1]))
    return RMA_TR_Results[RMA_TR_Results.length - 1] * multiplier
}

static superTrend = async(candles, multiplier, limit) => {
  let upperBands = []
  let lowerBands = []
  let superTrends = []
  for (let i = 0; i < candles.length; i++) {
    if (i >= limit * 4) {
      const lastCandle = +candles[i - 1].close
      const currentCandling = +candles[i].close
      const candlesATR = await this.ATR(candles.slice(i - (limit * 4), limit * 4), multiplier, limit)
      const basicUpperBand = ((+candles[i].high + +candles[i].low) / 2) - candlesATR
      const basicLowerBand = ((+candles[i].high + +candles[i].low) / 2) + candlesATR
      if (i === limit * 4) {
        upperBands.push(basicUpperBand)
        lowerBands.push(basicLowerBand)
        superTrends.push(true)
      } else {
        const lastUpperBand = upperBands[upperBands.length - 1]
        const lastLowerBand = lowerBands[lowerBands.length - 1]
        upperBands.push(lastCandle > lastUpperBand ? Math.max(basicUpperBand, lastUpperBand) : basicUpperBand)
        lowerBands.push(lastCandle < lastLowerBand ? Math.min(basicLowerBand, lastLowerBand) : basicLowerBand)
        const lastSuperTrend = superTrends[superTrends.length - 1]
        superTrends.push(!lastSuperTrend && currentCandling > lastLowerBand ? true : lastSuperTrend && currentCandling < lastUpperBand ? false : lastSuperTrend)
      }
    }
  }
  return superTrends[superTrends.length - 1]
}

// Running the super trend
const supertrendResult = await superTrend(candles, 2, 14)
```

Again any help is appreciated!

Heres some more resources i am using:

[RMA Calculation](https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/relative-moving-average/) (in pinescript)

```
    pine_rma(source, length) =>
    alpha = 1 / length
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? 
         ta.sma(source, length) : 
         alpha * source + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])
    plot(pine_rma(close, 15))
```

[TR Calculation](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000501823-average-true-range-atr/)

```
   true range = max[(high - low), abs(high - previous close), abs (low - previous close)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.  Its with the way did the splice

```
const candlesATR = await this.ATR(candles.slice(i - (limit * 4), limit * 4), multiplier, limit)
```

Should be:

```
const candlesATR = await this.ATR(candles.slice(i - (limit * 4), i), multiplier, limit)
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you multiply the period by 4 both in ATR and in super trend calculations, is there a specific reason?